# second external javascript file not loaded

Tags: javascript, external

I have these lines in my html head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../behaviour/location.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../behaviour/ajax.js"></script>
```

When I use either in isolation, the code in the external files executes as expected.

However, when I use both, I find that neither works correctly. What do I need to do to fix this?

location.js

```
// JavaScript Document

function addLoadEvent (func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function () {
            oldonload();
            func;
        }
    }
}

//county changer
function countyUpdate (message) {

    var name = message.getAttribute("name");
    var check = message.checked;
    var countyId = message.getAttribute("id");
    var countyId = countyId.split("_")[1];
    var innerpost = document.getElementById("innerpost_"+countyId); 
    var checks = innerpost.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i< checks.length; i++) {
        if (checks[i].checked == true && check == true) {
        checks[i].checked = false; 
        }
    }

}

//postcode changer
function postcodeUpdate (message) {
    var parent = message.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("id").split("_")[1];
    var county = "county_"+parent;
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(county);
    var checked = message.checked;

    if (checked == true) {
        checkbox.checked = false;
    }


}

//get a dynamic list of al postcode checkboxes
function getCounties () {
var county = document.getElementsByTagName("input");


for (var i = 0; i< county.length; i++) {
var check = county[i].getAttribute("type");

if (check == "checkbox") {  
var name = county[i].getAttribute("name");
var parent = county[i].parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
var parent = parent.split("_")[0];

//action for county
if (parent != "innerpost") {
county[i].onclick = function() { countyUpdate(this); };

    }//if


    //action for postcode
    if (parent == "innerpost") {
    county[i].onclick = function() { postcodeUpdate (this); }; 
    }//if

    }//if
    }//for
    }//function

    addLoadEvent (getCounties);
```

ajax.js

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cart.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And this is the inline code to activate the second file:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

When I try using both files together, I don't seem to be able to use any functions (not even simple alerts wrapped in a function).

Comment: its pretty hard to fix something if we don't have the code.

Comment: Also, it's a little tedious to have to exercise my supernatural powers of divination in order to figure out what exactly happens when your code doesn't "execute as expected."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that you're getting a mess out of that `window.onload=` juggling. I suggest you use the standard `window.addEventListener()` interface (check for its existance and use `window.attachEvent()` when the standard interface is missing if you want to support IE too). This should also guarantee that the onload functions get executed in the same order as the scripts that set them. Something like:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', somefunc, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', somefunc);
} // else, no way to add multiple onload handlers
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with addEventListener. Could you explain it a little? Can I attach multiple functions to it?

Comment: Well I tried replacing my function with that and I didn't see any difference.

Answer (score 2):

This would happen if the scripts conflict with each other.

Please show us the scripts and the error messages.

Comment: +1 Not a clue.  That's kinda lame that it was.  What you said makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

> When I use either in isolation, the
>   code in the external files executes as
>   expected.
>
> However, when I use both, I find that
>   neither works correctly. What do I
>   need to do to fix this?

It sounds like you have a conflict somewhere in the two files.  Like a function that is named the same or a variable etc.

Having not seen the files you could:
1.  Track down the naming conflict (if that is what it is) and change one.
2.  Encapsulate the code in the files in different objects and access the methods/properties etc. through there.